# Memory management question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *TelephoneCellId = @"TelephoneCellId";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TelephoneCellId];

    UIImageView *imgView;
    UILabel *lblName;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TelephoneCellId] autorelease];

        UIView *uiview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 90.0)];

        imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 60.0, 60.0)] autorelease];
        imgView.tag = IMAGE_TAG;
        [uiview addSubview:imgView];

        lblName = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 10.0, 200.0, 20.0)] autorelease];
        lblName.tag = NAME_TAG;
        [uiview addSubview:lblName];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:uiview];
        [uiview release];
    } else {
        imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:IMAGE_TAG];
        lblName = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:NAME_TAG];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [[[self.telephoneList objectForKey:[self.keys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] retain];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"image"]];

    lblName.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

    [dict release];
    return cell;
}
```

In the code above I got a question about the retaining and autoreleasing. If the UITableViewCell returning from the que is nil, then I have to make a new one. As I do so I autorelease the label and the image. Then I set the text/image. If the UITableViewCell is NOT nil then I find the view by tag, however this would return an autoreleased object. Should I retain it? Then release after I am done setting the value? Or is this okey because the view retains it so it is atleast 1 therefore it is safe to not release?

Help on such scenarios would be much appreciated, so to sum up, when would it be okay to just carry on setting/getting values on an autoreleased object?

Thank you for your time:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've over thinking this.

Do you want this function to take ownership of an object (and, therefore, responsibility for it)? No, of course not. Therefore, don't retain for this function's sake.

Do you want the view controller this code is in to take responsibility for an object? No: You want to leave that in UIKit's hands. Therefore, don't retain for the view controller's sake.

Conclusion: If you don't want to take ownership, you don't retain.

Also, don't bother retaining (and later, releasing) the dictionary. Even if it's been autoreleased to the point that it'll disappear soon, that "soon" won't be while this function is running.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an *auto*released object, you can manipulate its properties, pass it an an argument to other methods, and even return it as the return value from your method. But you can't store it in an ivar, global variable, or static variable without retaining it.

The label that you find by tag is not actually autoreleased, though. It's just an object that you don't own. You could retain and then release it, but that is not necessary.

The main situations to watch out for are:

- When you fetch an object from a collection and then remove the object from the collection, the collection will release it. So you will have to retain it if you want to keep it.
- When you are writing a setter method, you have to be careful to handle the case where someone does effectively `[object setFoo:object.foo]`. If you release the old value before retaining the new, that case could wind up sending `retain` to a deallocated object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no need to retain it. You also don't need to retain and release the dictionary.